# Attach dynamically generated visual force PDF to a visual force template

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, attachment, apex-email-service

I have a requirement where I need to attach a dynamically generated VF PDF to an email generated with an email template. Though I am able to send the template, I am not able to send the attachment. Please suggest how can this be achieved.

Comment: You mean you have a VF email template with attachment, you build a link to emailAuthor.jsp with the template preselected and it doesn't add the attachment? Or are you sending the email form apex code? Your selection of tags is bit confusing...

Comment: I have used a VF Template. My attachment is also a dynamically rendered PDF but I am not able to attach PDF to the template. And i am sending that email as from apex code.

Comment: Have you seen http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_messaging_attachment.htm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the as suggested in comment.

`<messaging:attachment renderAs="PDF" filename="yourCases.pdf">`

I had a blog post almost years back that you can take help from

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.in/2012/11/sending-document-as-attachment-in-form.html